# LINQ to SQL with SQL Azure

Tags: azure, linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

We are investigating moving to a cloud model and the Microsoft Azure PaaS platform.

Our current data layer is written using LINQ to SQL. Will it be compatible with SQL Azure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes LINQ to SQL is compatible. But you have to keep 2 things in mind:

- SQL Azure is not a dedicated machine for you alone. Your databases will run on machines with other customers. You may be throttled, you can encounter transient exceptions, ... That's why you should implement a retry policy. There's an [article on TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4235.retry-logic-for-transient-failures-in-windows-azure-sql-database-en-us.aspx) explaining how to do this with LINQ to SQL.
- Since SQL Azure is not a real SQL Server there are some limitations. Read all about those limitations here: [General Guidelines and Limitations (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx). If you're planning to move an existing database (with or without data) to SQL Azure, consider using a tool that supports SQL Azure like the [SQL Database Migration Wizard (SQLAzureMW)](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).

Comment: New Azure SQL Database should be more reliable in performance today (obsoleting the first statement). http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Storage-SQL-Database-Tutorials/Scott-Klein-Video-02